# Running Angular and AngularJS frameworks side by side

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I have found resources that describe how to integrate Angular (2) components into AngularJS, but all of these have involved setting up the AngularJS project like an Angular project, requiring a transpiler from TypeScript, requiring ES6, requiring import statements. I want to simply use Angular components in my AngularJS application without disrupting my existing workflow. Is this possible, and if so how do I implement it? I thought that this was the purpose of the upgrade module, but all  the tutorials I have seen require import statements in the AngularJS application, which requires a transpiler. If the Angular application needs to be transpiled ahead of time, that is ok, but the AngularJS application cannot be transpiled because it is running on a django server, and I don't want to run another server with a transpiler.

To be clear, my current AngularJS application is being served by django. I want to include some Angular components. These won't be touched during development, so they can be transpiled ahead of time without affecting workflow. Is there a way of adding these components into the AngularJS app without adding a transpiler to the AngularJS app?

Comment: Just for clarity ... the transpiler is run on the client *before* being deployed to the server. So no need to set anything special up on your server.

Answer (score 20):

## Incrementally upgrade an AngularJS application to Angular.

> One of the keys to a successful upgrade is to do it incrementally, by **running the two frameworks side by side in the same application**, and porting AngularJS components to Angular one by one. This makes it possible to upgrade even large and complex applications without disrupting other business, because the work can be done collaboratively and spread over a period of time. The `upgrade` module in Angular has been designed to make incremental upgrading seamless.

For more information, see [Angular 2 Guide - Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/6TYZDjwfsWUdUIS64vJ3?p=preview)

See also,

- [Migrating AngularJS to Angular 4,5 (with DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312788/migrating-angular-1-to-angular-4)

---

> I don't want to run another server with a transpiler.

The transpiler can be run client-side. It is possible but not recommended.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

#### systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * WEB ANGULAR VERSION
 * (based on systemjs.config.js in angular.io)
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      // Copy of compiler options in standard tsconfig.json
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs@5.0.1',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'ts':                        'npm:plugin-typescript@5.2.7/lib/plugin.js',
      'typescript':                'npm:typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js',

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts',
        meta: {
          './*.ts': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });

})(this);
```

For more information, see [Angular 2 TypeScript QuickStart](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

---

### Convert Angular TypeScript examples into ES6 and ES5 JavaScript.

Anything you can do with Angular in *TypeScript*, you can also do in JavaScript. Translating from one language to the other is mostly a matter of changing the way you organize your code and access Angular APIs.

For more information, see [Angular 2 Developer Cookbook - TypeScript to JavaScript](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html)

Comment: This is neat but I haven't been able to get this to work locally. It seems set up specifically for the example, and not recommended for a real application. Then, it seems that what I'm asking is not possible. Perhaps my question was not clear: I want to transpile the Angular 2 components ahead of time, then use them as AngularJS directives in my AngularJS app, without including the Angular 2 imports like webpack and transpilers. I'll update my question.

Comment: Added additonal info on TS to JS.

Comment: Thanks but the code has already been written in TS. I guess the answer is no :(