# Bootstrap an Angular 2 app, side-by-side with an already loaded Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, angular

On a particular website, there is an **Angularjs** app that I don't control. It's loaded on the HTML when I open the page. Let's call it **app 1** :

```
<body data-ng-app="app1">.....</body>
```

My chrome plugin inserts an **Angular 2** app in the HTML of the websites I visit. Let's call it **app 2**. I normally insert it with this code :

```
$('body').append('<app-root id="app-root"></app-root>');
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But this doesn't work.

==> The problem is, the Angularjs "**app 1**" is located directly in the body. So how can I insert my Anglular 2 "**app 2**" in the HTML, side-by-side?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the `ng-app` auto-bootstrap directive needs to be removed to work with the ng-upgrade module. The AngularJS app needs to be bootstrapped manually by the ng-upgrade module. See [Angular Developer Guide - Bootstrapping hybrid applications](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Angular 1 to Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312788/migrating-angular-1-to-angular-4/44312853#44312853).

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure if this will work (never tried angular 2 as a chrome extension app)

```
$('html').append('<app-root id="app-root"></app-root>');
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

or create a `div` element and use `insertAdjacentHTML` inside the `body` with `afterbegin` position 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: It "works" in that it processes my angular code. But because I am outside of the <body>, my modal doesn't show up on the screen

Comment: you can fix that with css i think. just try some `position: absolute` or `fixed` and high enough `z-index`