# Migration of Angular 1.x app to Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, web-applications

How to Migrate a large web-app from Angular 1.4 to Angular 5. 
I go through different tutorial and have't find right answer.
If someone already done this milestone please guide.
There is no solution i have found anywhere.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you go to that post there is no answer, no relevant solution suggested.

Comment: There is an answer posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312853/3148590).

Comment: in my opinion, migrate application from angularjs 1 to angular 5 need so much effort such as, rewrite in typescript, CodingStyle, avoid dirty checking forcing... Than is not justifiable than just, do again your project from beginning, improve, btw your application. Tipical case is RxJS who can really improve your CodingStyle and the way to manage state.

Comment: `There is no solution I have found anywhere.?` Really quite hard to fathom, did you visit Angular's  official website [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-from-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with both versions and I must say the best way to migrate your project, is to rewrite it in Angular 5. I understand your project is large and at the time of development you have spent a lot of time and energy on it. But Angular 1.x and Angular 2+ are so different from each other that rewriting efforts will be far less than trying to convert your code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Our project has taken more than a year for development. And the project is live on production , is this good approach to re-write it. Please suggest

Comment: I recommend you keep the project live and start rewriting your project on a test server. It will take 2 -3 months at most for a trained developer to rewrite and test. The result will be so amazing it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and great suggestions