# Migration from Angular1 to Angular5 (parallel run)

Tags: angularjs, django, migration, angular5, angular-hybrid

My current AngularJS application is being served by django. Now our team in a position to migrate Angular1 to Angular5. It should run parallelly. Our application is very big and legacy. I checked angular doc, which has `ngupgrade` which will help us to migrate things. I am here just looking for a repo or example to run both Angular1 and Angular5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312788/migrating-angular-1-to-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

You can clone this repo https://github.com/upgradingangularjs/ordersystem-project. Just go to commit 083ee533d44c05db003413186fbef41f76466976

git checkout 083ee533d44c05db003413186fbef41f76466976.

In this commit they are bootstrapping both angular 5 and angularjs. And having one component in Angular 5 and rest in angularjs.