# Migrate older angular version to newer angular version

Tags: angular

I have a large angular project. I am using angular version 5 in my project. Now I want to migrate to newer angular version. How can I do that?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Hope this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312788/migrating-angularjs-to-angular-4-5-with-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to update version by version, and the dependencies (many have breaking changes) along with it. This helps escpecially when errors occur. https://update.angular.io/?v=5.0-6.0 provides general steps how to update from Angular 5 to Angular 6. For this version update one of the biggest changes are connected to the rxjs library. You could install rxjs-compat (compat = compatibility) temporary.